# Android Studio with Flutter no devices connected

Tags: android-studio, dart

I've installed Android Studio with Flutter/Dart plugin on Windows 10.

- Android Studio 3.4.2
- Flutter Plugin 38.2
- Dart Plugin v183.6270

If I open a Flutter project in Android Studio, the device list always displays "loading", and I see my three devices:

- Android Accelerated x86 Oreo
- Nexus 4 API 28
- Nexus 6 API 28

[image: device list]]

I selected one device and it opens on the emulator, but when I start the project this error message is displayed:

> No Connected Devices Found
>   No connected devices found; please connect a device,
>   or see flutter.io/setup for getting started instructions.

[image: no device connected]]

When I run `flutter devices`, the device is listed as connected:

```
PS C:\users\vsysm03> flutter devices
1 connected device:

Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
PS C:\users\vsysm03>
```

[[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwIle.png)

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is necessarily wrong. You merely have a decision at any time to 
**develop your app on a real device, or, forgoing an actual device, to use an emulation of the desired device.**

The "No connected devices found" alert is informing you that you have not connected a *physical* device.

The notice "1 connected device...**emulator**..." shows you have chosen to target Android 9 for this particular project. The "emulator-5554" is now emulating an actual device that your application runs in as you develop, as though you had connected an actual device via USB cable to your workstation/computer. Please see the [Android Virtual Device Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) for more information. Look for this icon in Android Studio. It opens AVD manager for you: [image: https://developer.android.com/studio/images/buttons/toolbar-avd-manager.png].

Of course, if you prefer to test your application on a live device, in real time, [you only have the small duty to connect one](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app#RealDevice). This is easily done having gone into settings to place your phone in **Debug mode**. Please be aware you may also need to choose **Airplane mode** if your phone is not responding to your application run/debug commands. When your phone is connected live, of course, the "No connected devices" notice no longer appears.